# How can we make the work spaces like 2X2 Grid on Ubuntu18.04?

Tags: 18.04, workspaces

Ubuntu 18.04 shows the workspace vertically. All work spaces shows below ones.
How can we make it like as previous (2X2 Grid)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a gnome extension [Workspace Grid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/)

> Size of grid and keybinding are configurable, GitHub pages listed all the configuration option [github page](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid)

Comment: Do you know how to switch between windows by Alt+Tab in just one workspace, instead of switching between windows in all workspaces?

Comment: @BioCoder [Windows Alt Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/38/windows-alt-tab/) this is probably the extension you need.

Comment: The [Workspace Matrix](https://github.com/mzur/gnome-shell-wsmatrix) extension is better than Workspace Grid in my experience. Workspace Grid currently has problems with 18.04.