# No 2x2 workspaces in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: workspaces

I really liked the 2x2 workspaces from ubuntu 14.04 LTS but on 18.04 LTS they only made a vertical one. I could still live with this if this was the only difference but my main problem is the fact that once I'm in one of my workspaces and I want to toggle in between windows I still have to toggle through all the other windows from the other workspaces.

Is this solvable by just changing some settings?

Or do I have to download separate software?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm not a very experienced linux user.

Comment: Also: [How can we make the work spaces like 2X2 Grid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043117/how-can-we-make-the-work-spaces-like-2x2-grid)